# Animate trajectory of Brownian motion

Tags: random, animation

I'm hoping to animate the trajectory of a 2D Brownian Motion. Here's my attempt, which is based on what I've read in Mathematica's documentation:

```
SeedRandom[666];
Animate[ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, T, .001}, 2]["ValueList"]]], 
  {T, 0, 0.04}, 
  AnimationRunning -> False]
```

There are two things that I'm seeking help with:

1. It doesn't look like the seed is fixed. When I animate the parameter T (the ending time of the Brownian Motion), it appears as though I get a different trajectory after each time step.
2. I'd like the window to be of fixed size. For example, having each of the horizontal and vertical axes to range from -1 to 1.

Please let me know if you can help with either of these two items.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the randomness problem, generate the random walk just once. To fix (pun intended*) the size of the plot area, use the `PlotRange` option.

```
SeedRandom[666]
endTime = .05;
data =
  Transpose[
    RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, endTime, .001}, 2]["ValueList"]]

With[{s = .25},
  Animate[
    Graphics[Line[data[[;; i]]],
      Frame -> True,
      PlotRange -> s {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
    {i, 1, Length[data], 1},
    AnimationRunning -> False]]
```

[image: plot]

* For those readers who are not native-level English speakers, "fix" can mean both "repair" and "hold in place".

#### Update

After thinking more about this problem, I decided that I didn't like specifying an a-priori size for the plotting area. It is better to compute a plot rectangle that exactly contains the whole random walk. Here is how to do that.

```
SeedRandom[1]
endTime = .2;
data =
  Transpose[
   RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, endTime, .001}, 2]["ValueList"]];

Module[{xrange, yrange},
  xrange = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
  yrange = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]];
  Animate[
    Graphics[Line[data[[;; i]]],
      Frame -> True,
      PlotRange -> {xrange, yrange}],
    {i, 1, Length[data], 1},
    AnimationRunning -> False,
    DefaultDuration -> 15]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks very much! This is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the region:

```
SeedRandom[666];
Animate[
 ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[
   RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, t, .001}, 2]["ValueList"]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-.5, .5}, {-.5, .5}}], 
 {t, 0, 0.04},
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Note the use of lower-case `t` rather than `T`, to avoid potential conflicts with *Mathematica*'s internal naming conventions.

More fundamentally, you seem to have a conceptual error:  Your code produces a separate random walk for each time.  There is no link between one time and the next... in short your animation does *not* show the progression of Brownian motion of a particle.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that my code gives a different random walk for each time and I'm trying to figure out which part of my code needs to be changed to fix this issue. I thought that setting the seed at the beginning would yield the same "random" function, but to different ending times specified by the parameter t. Do you have any suggestions?